# ionic 2 - android returns black screen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

the code seems to run fine when ionic serve is used..

but when tested on android device..  using ionic cordova run android a black screen appears.. and thats it.

the debug window throws the following message..

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    Unexpected closing tag "ion-row". It may happen when the tag has 
    already been closed by another tag. For more info see 
    https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("

    </ion-col>
    [ERROR ->]</ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    "): ng:///AppModule/HistDetailComponent.html@31:2
```

my code seems fine..

code:

```
    <ion-grid class='bgdivCenter' text-center>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
      <span class="headingDisp">Detail Chart</span>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
  <div class="chart">
    <canvas baseChart width="400" height="auto"
            [datasets]="detailData"
            [labels]="detailLabel"
            [options]="detailChartOptions"
            [colors]="detailColors"
            [legend]="detailLegends"
            [chartType]="detailChartType"></canvas>
  </div>

     </ion-col>
     </ion-row>


    </ion-grid>
```

any help would be great!.